# Electron Packager - set App Icons for OSX & Windows

Tags: electron

I am building my electron application with electron packager for windows and OSX platform.

**package.json:**

`"build": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist --ignore='^/dist$' --prune --all --icon=icon.icns"`

I run my build process with `npm run build`.

**Question:**

How can I use the electron packager script in my package.json to set the windows AND osx Icon?

**Problem:**

The above script sets the app icon for OSX only.
It doesnt set the icon for the windows app (NPM throws failure).

**Solution:**

I had to install wine on my OSX. Otherwise it is not possible to build the windows exe with the --icon tag. Why? Because electron-packager uses node-rcedit for that, which requires wine.

in my package.json:

```
"pack:osx": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/osx --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/build/osx/icon.icns && npm run codesign",
"pack:win32": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/win --platform=win32 --arch=ia32",
"pack:win64": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/win --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --version=0.36.2 app-version=1.0 --icon=assets/build/win/icon.ico",
"build": "npm run pack:osx && npm run pack:win32 && npm run pack:win64"
```

`npm run build` to start the process..

Comment: `--icon=icon.ico` does not work for me. Any idea why? Maybe a missing npm package?

Comment: I figured out, that i had to install wine when building windows apps on OSX. But now I get the following error:  `wine: '/Users/X/.wine' is a 64-bit installation, it cannot be used with a 32-bit wineserver.
 undefined` Any Ideas on that?

Comment: I removed wine from my system (osx) an reinstalled it with brew install wine. Now everything is working fine. I adjusted my solution above!

Comment: Could you move your solution to a separate answer and mark the question as answered. It still shows up as unanswered, even though you found the solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Solution:**

I had to install wine on my OSX. Otherwise it is not possible to build the windows exe with the --icon tag. Why? Because electron-packager uses node-rcedit for that, which requires wine.

in my package.json:

```
"pack:osx": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/osx --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/build/osx/icon.icns && npm run codesign",
"pack:win32": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/win --platform=win32 --arch=ia32",
"pack:win64": "electron-packager . $npm_package_productName --out=dist/win --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --version=0.36.2 app-version=1.0 --icon=assets/build/win/icon.ico",
"build": "npm run pack:osx && npm run pack:win32 && npm run pack:win64"
```

`npm run build` to start the process..

Comment: I'm using a windows machine, and when I use `npm run build` I get a page full of errors. When I enter `electron-packager ./ Match --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=build --icon=./images/icons/icon.png` I'm able to build the project. Do I not have something installed correctly?

Comment: Nevermind... I figured out my error. I didn't place it within the `"scripts": { }` command.

Comment: Have you placed the assets folder on the root of the project? I have got this error Error: Unknown target: icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns

Comment: So your script cannot find the icns file. try playing around with the correct data path. I think i placed the assets folder on the same level as package.json

Answer (score 5):

You can package your electron app into an executable using electron-packager
Which can be installed using

```
npm install --save-dev electron-packager
```

After that, run this command

- dir - specify app source is stored
- appName -  The name you want to call the app
- option --icon helps you add an app icon, eg: mine is stored in build
  folder
- option --arch specifies target system architecture(s)
- version option for specifying the version of electron you are compiling
  with(look in package.json for specific of electron you are using)

> run

```
npx electron-packager dir appName --overwrite --asar --electron-version=13.4.0 --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds --icon=./build/icon.ico
```

These are some of the most important options. if you need any certifications, Let me know

Comment: Great update to your answer. That looks more informative.

Comment: I am running this command "electron-packager . appName --overwrite --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/images/logos/logo-72x72.png --prune=true --out=release-builds", but the packaging is not happening. Node version is 15.3, can you help

Comment: npx electron-packager . appName --overwrite --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/images/logos/logo-72x72.png --prune=true --out=release-builds

Comment: Run the command in your project directory. The output will be stored in release-builds. Secondly, Every Electron version comes with its own node version installed

Comment: install npx if you haven't, npx allows you to use node packages without installing it dependencies

Comment: Your command looks fine, but try the second one and let's see what happens, remember to install npx if you haven't, npx allows you to use node packages without installing it dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Holy moly, did this take me forever to figure out. The application name cannot contain any illegal characters (no uppercase or hyphens etc.). Oddly the executable name WOULD be correctly generated with this "illegal" characters, but the icon would fail to apply!

**Wrong format**

```
electron-packager ./electron APPLICATION-NAME --overwrite --asar --electron-version=13.1.7 --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds --icon=./icon.ico"
```

**Correct Format**

```
electron-packager ./electron applicationname --overwrite --asar --electron-version=13.1.7 --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds --icon=./icon.ico"
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot mate, really helped me out here.
I smashed that ^ Upvote button!