# Unable to create windows app package with electron-packager

Tags: angular, windows, ionic3, electron, electron-packager

I want to create a windows app package from my existing ionic cordova application,I am using electron-packager for the same but getting below error:
[image]

npm version:5.6.0,electron-packager version: ^11.2.1

I have Added following command  in package.json script :

```
"electron:win": "electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=./assets/icon/favicon.png  --out=./build/win --version-string.CompanyName=Mob --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=MobTestApp"
```

Executing following :

> npm run electron:win

**after** command

> ionic cordova build windows

And I have referred to : [Electron Packager - set App Icons for OSX & Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941605/electron-packager-set-app-icons-for-osx-windows)
also I have followed this tutorial for the same: https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

I am unable to understand cause of error.
Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

**Edited** :

Now i have progressed from the error which i was getting while creating a package and used a command:

```
electron-packager ./src --platform=win32 --arch=ia32  --out=./build/win6 --version-string.CompanyName=Mob --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=MobTestApp
```

to create a package for windows build, and created a successful package for the same but whenever I try to run the app .exe  file getting error as :
[image]

What should I do resolve the error and create a successful build for windows using electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to resolve the electron-packager issue due to the dependencies on internally distributed plugins and packages. After trying multiple options I found "electron-builder" useful to create successful build of ".exe"  and ".appx" for windows.

**Requirements** :

1. NodeJS version should be more than 8.0.
2. If you have any **internally distributed package dependencies** then please make sure to add them in package.json file  in **build.extraFiles** like:

   { "build": {
   "extraFiles": [
   "node_modules/module-name/**/*"
   ]
   }}
3. For more information I found this useful: [Check this](http://%20https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration)